# piping paths via xargs to `tag` command line tool

Tags: bash, variables, pipe, xargs

[tag](https://github.com/jdberry/tag) is a command line executable that allows macOS users to add a "tag" to a file.

`tag -a | --add <tags> <path>...     Add tags to file`

I am trying to pipe a list of files in a text document but after a few days of failing badly need help on the syntax. The only clue on the description page is this:

> If you plan to pipe the output of tag through xargs, you might want to
> use the -0 option of each.

I have tried dozens of commands: xargs, gnu-xargs, for, while, and cannot get this to add tags to the files in the list. Researching the net I thought maybe there was an issue with line endings.

I installed `dos2unix` and ran it on the file to fix possible line ending issues, but that didn't appear to resolve anything.

If you `cd` into the directory of the files you are attempting to tag you don't have to use the complete path to the file.

```
$ gxargs -0 -t --arg-file="/Users/john/Desktop/diffremove.txt" | tag -0 -a red

echo '13.Hours.The.Secret.Soldiers.of.Benghazi.2016.1080p.BluRay.x265'$'\n''1941.1979.DC.1080p.BluRay.x265'$'\n'...
```

Not understanding how xargs passes the lines I thought I need to put a variable in position after the command where it's looking for the file `tag -0 -a red <variable here>`

I tried:
`` $ for i in $(/Users/john/Desktop/diffremove.txt) do `tag -a red "$1"` ``

I installed `gnu xargs` and tried this command.

```
$ </Users/john/Desktop/diffremove.txt gxargs -0 sh -c 'for arg do tag -0 -a red "$arg"'
```

EDIT:
Trying this command results in no errors but the files aren't tagged.

```
$ </Users/john/Desktop/diffremove.txt xargs -0 sh -c 'for arg do `tag -0 -a red '$arg'`;done'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
xargs -d '\n' -a /Users/john/Desktop/diffremove.txt -I % tag -a red %
```

here we use xargs to read from file (using -a), using replacing string with (using %) and execute command *tag -a red {filename}*. You may need to add *-d '\n'* (setting delimeter to newline) to split strings.

However, classic way to read and process lines in file is using shell builtin command **read**:

```
$ while IFS= read -r p; do tag -a red $p; done < /Users/john/Desktop/diffremove.txt
```

,where *IFS=* part can be skipped if you don't have spaces in file.

Comment: This is gnu xargs?

Comment: The issue appears to that the file names are being turned into one long string instead of breaking at the newline.

Comment: yes, https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/xargs-options.html , which one you need?

Comment: I am on a mac but have installed gnu xargs.

Comment: tag: The item couldn’t be opened because the file name “ long list of lines"  is invalid.

Comment: hm, try adding -d '\n' option to xargs

Comment: OK! Here is what worked. `$ gxargs -d '\n' -a /Users/john/Desktop/diffremove.txt -I % tag  -a red %`. After adding `-d '\n` option I removed `-0` from `gxargs` and `tag`.

Comment: thanks for the help! How would we write this if I didn't have gnu xargs installed?